# Trying to Understand Numerical Integration Using Python Syntax

Tags: python, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am trying to learn to program in Python.  While I will use the built-in functions in the future, I want to understand how to program the routines from scratch as I believe it will better help me understand Python syntax and coding much better.  I have been trying to write a program to numerically integrate a function by direct summation.  I have been unable to figure out what changes I need to make to my program to get this to work in Python and some help would be appreciated.

```
from math import *
import numpy as np

N = int(input("Enter value for how many sums you wish to perform: "))
a = float(input("Enter the lower integration bound: "))
b = float(input("Enter the higher integration bound: "))

def Integrate(N, a, b):
    def f(x):
        return x**2 * e**(-x)*np.sin(x)
    val = 0
    out = 0
    for i in range(N):
        function += f(a+((i-(1/2))*((b-a)/N)))
    out = ((b-a)/N)*val
    return out
```

I tried the above code and I am not even obtaining an output, so I suspect there is something regarding the Python language I am missing.

Comment: Add `result = Integrate(N, a, b)` at the bottom to call this function. And to display the output, `print(result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic example of numerical integration, [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) with a uniformly partitioned interval.

For convenience the function is passed as argument.

```
def Integrate(N, a, b, f):
    # Riemann integral, evaluation at the midpoint of each interval
    width = (b-a) / float(N)
    return sum(f(a+(i+.5)*width)*width for i in range(N))


N = 10
a = 0
b = 1

# testing the area of a triangle

# test function - diagonal
def diagonal(x): return x

numerical_approx = Integrate(N, a, b, f=diagonal)
exact_area = (b-a)*diagonal(b) / 2 # base * height / 2

error = abs(numerical_approx - exact_area
print(f"{error):.20f}")
#0.00000000000000011102
```

The fact that the difference of areas is not zero is due to computational limitations of the `float` data types.

---

For the original problem

```
def f(x):
    return x**2 * np.e**(-x)*np.sin(x)

N, a, b = 10, 0, 1

I = Integrate(N=N, a=a, b=b, f=f)
print(I)
#0.10225500155762644
```

for a rough check you can use [`numpy.trap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) which use a [trapezoidal approximation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). Also if the result could be slightly different it is a good indicator (any integrable function will converge to the same value independently from the partion)

```
width = (b-a) / float(N)
y = [f(a+(i)*width) for i in range(N+1) ]
I_trap = np.trapz(y, dx=width)
print(I_trap)
#0.10289249898529564
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  The big mistake that was escaping me was the fact that even after I was prompted to enter my parameters, I still needed to call the function I defined or explicitly write that call into the program before running it.  I know full well I could have used the trapezoid approximation and/or a built-in function to calculate such an integral, but I wanted to hash out these 'simple' issues in Python so that I learn the structure of the language far more fully.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
from math import exp

N = int(input("Enter value for how many sums you wish to perform: "))
a = float(input("Enter the lower integration bound: "))
b = float(input("Enter the higher integration bound: "))

def Integrate(N, a, b):
    def f(x):
        return x**2 * exp(-x) * sin(x)

    val = 0
    for i in range(N):
        val += f(a + ((i + 0.5) * ((b - a) / N)))
    
    out = ((b - a) / N) * val
    return out

result = Integrate(N, a, b)
print("Integration result:", result)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  So once one makes a definition, one then must call it explicitly in the shell after one sets parameters unless one explicitly writes this into the code as you have done.  Note that I had to make one correction to the above code, i.e. I had to call NumPy and define sin(x) -> np.sin(x) using the 'method' sin in NumPy.  Thanks for the help!